# How to measure the number of words the user has read in webview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am implementing gamification in my app. How can I measure the number of words a user has read in a webview in my app? I want to measure their progress in the webview. Have they gone through 50% of the content or 25%? I know I can inject javascript in the webview. How can I do this specific task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebView has a `scrollView` instance. You can read its `contentOffset` property to see how far have they scrolled.

Comment: Is there a function I can call that is called whenever someone scrolls?

Comment: @LouisaScheinost Through the [`UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate) you can get notifications from the scroll view by setting yourself up as the scroll view's `delegate`.